# How to Deploy Streamlit App without requirements file?

Tags: python, deployment, streamlit

I am deploying a streamlit web app on its own servers.

The app requires cartopy. However, cartopy has c++ dependencies which a user might not have. Is there a way to (easily) deploy the app without making a requirements file?

Comment: Who are you concerned about in this case, you being able to deploy on Streamlit sharing or someone in the future who wants to run your app locally? In either case, having the dependencies specified is the right way to go.

Comment: The main goal is to share the app on the web. If I can't do this with Streamlit, I'm happy to use a different library. I have 0 experience with web development, though, so I don't know where to start. Would I need to deploy this in the cloud (AWS or GCP?)

Comment: No matter where you try to host it, you'll need to provide a requirements file. It's unlikely any host is going to have exactly what you need installed on it, with the exact versions you require.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!